# How to set azure resource alert with terraform with alerting conditions

Tags: azure, terraform, alert, terraform-provider-azure, azure-alerts

Below is the documentation to create the alert :
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_activity_log_alert

It seems to work fine the only thing missing is we are not able to select the alerting condition via terraform. Like we only want alerted on when current resource status is degraded or unavailable, and reason type is platform initiated.
Terraform seems to be giving all to all the conditions.

Is there a work around ?

Comment: This isn't really helpful. Please post the code you are using as then we might now what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: please provide the code that you have tried .. so that we can try to reproduce the same and provide solution